# Unit test hanging when using lexical scoping and generics with extends

Tags: dart

The behavior seems to be related to the presence of 'extends' as shown with unit test below:

```dart
typedef dynamic GetFromThing<T extends Thing>(T target);

typedef GetFromThing<T> DefGetFromThing<T extends Thing>(dynamic def);

typedef dynamic GetFromT<T>(T target);

typedef GetFromT<T> DefGetFromT<T>(dynamic def);

class Thing {
  int value;
}

class Test {

  static final GetFromThing<Thing> fromThingSimple = (Thing target) {
    return target.value;
   };

  static final DefGetFromThing<Thing> fromThing = (dynamic def) {
    return (target) => null;
  };

  static final DefGetFromT<int> fromInt = (dynamic def) {
    return (target) => null;
  };

}

main() {
  test('this works', () {
    var temp1 = Test.fromThingSimple(new Thing());
  });

  test('this works too', () {
    var temp = Test.fromInt(10);
  });

  test('should let me call lexically closed functions', () {
    var temp = Test.fromThing(10); // <-- causes test to hang
  });
}
```

Comment: Try filing a bug? https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the VM hangs is clearly a bug. The code is legal. The fact that typedefs describe function types and can be generic  whereas function types themselves are never generic is not an issue in principle (though it might be for the implementation).

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I filed a bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9443.

Answer (score 1):

I find it very interesting that type parameters in typedefs work without some kind of warning or error, since Dart doesn't have generic methods.

You very well may have come across two bugs here, the first that there's no errors, and the second that the VM hangs.